# Is it possible to call module.exports on demand in Node?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an app where I call an API to get headlines and digest that JSON and send the data back to the client via sockets. I have modularized all my code and used different files to stay organized. I have my `index.js` file, where I merely call the functions to grab to data from the API and `newsDataFetcher.js` is where I make the request to the API for the data using the request module. My issue is that since the request I am making is asynchronous, the data doesn't get passed to the main server file and therefore the socket doesn't send any data. After the request to the API finishes, I put the data into an array and that array is in the `module.exports` of my `newsDataFetcher.js` file, along with the function that makes the actual request. So since the array is in the `module.exports`, an empty array is passed when I require the `newsDataFetcher.js` file in the `index.js` file. So, that brings me to the question: is there anyway to call `module.exports` "on demand" so that it doesn't pass an empty array and it only passes the array when the data is finished downloading from the API?

`index.js` :

```
var newsDataFetcher = require('./newsDataFetcher');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var news = []; //array for news headlines and abstracts

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views/routes/'));
server.listen(8888);
console.log("Running server on http://localhost:8888 ....");

newsDataFetcher.getNewsData();
news = newsDataFetcher.news;
setInterval(function () {
    newsDataFetcher.getNewsData();
    news = newsDataFetcher.news;
}, 6000000);
setInterval(function () {
    sendAllData()
}, 1000);

function sendAllData() {
    io.sockets.emit('news', news);
}
```

`newsDataFetcher.js` file:

```
var request = require('request');
var nyTimesApi = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v1/home.json?api-key=" + nyTimesApiKey_DEV;

var news = []; //array for news headlines and abstracts

function getNewsData() {
    request({
        url: nyTimesApi,
        json: true
    }, function (err, res, body) {
        news = body.results;
    });


}



module.exports = {
    getNewsData: getNewsData,
    news: news
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some like this:

```
// newsDataFetcher.js
module.exports = {
    getNewsData: getNewsData,
    news: function() {
        return news;
    }
}

// index.js
io.sockets.emit('news', newsDataFetcher.news());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use singleton pattern to achieve this.

```
class NewsDataFetcher {
    constructor() {
        this.news = [];
    }

    getNewsData() {
         const self = this;
         request({
             url: nyTimesApi,
             json: true
         }, function (err, res, body) {
             self.news = body.results;
         });
    }
}
module.exports = new NewsDataFetcher();
```

In the main page.

```
var newsDataFetcher = require('./newsDataFetcher');
newsDataFetcher.getNewsData(); // to fetch new data;
// To get news data
console.log(newsDataFetcher.news); // will always refer to one instance of news since you are using singleton.
```